# Prove that if transformation matrix is unitary, then the basis is orthonormal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, operator-theory

V is a vector space with the complex field, B is an orthonormal basis of V , and C is some arbitrary basis. Prove that if the transformation matrix from basis C to B is unitary, then C is also orthonormal basis.

can anyone give me some direction?

i've marked C={v1,v2,...,vn} and want to prove that 
if i=j then =1 and 0 otherwise but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $B = \{ w_1, w_2, . . ., w_n \}$ is an orthonormal basis, and that the unitary transformation $U$ satisfies $Uv_i = w_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$.  Then, since unitary transformations preserve the (supposedly Hermitian) inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on $V$, we have $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = \langle Uv_i, Uv_j \rangle = \langle w_i, w_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Season's Greetings,

and of course,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: can you explain me the unitary transformation? how does it get us wi? as i see it, the U(vi) it s not equal to wi but spanned by w1,...,wn

Comment: @CnR: I took your phrase, "transformation from basis $C$ to $B$ is unitary" to mean some unitary $U$ maps the $v_i$ to the $w_i$; if $U$ does not map the $v_i$ to the $w_i$, we still have $\langle Uv_i, Uv_j \rangle = \langle v_i, v_j \rangle$, but there is no way to know what the $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle$ without some further assumptions.  In this case, as far as I can tell, the $v_i$ will still be a basis, but not necessarily an orthonormal one.  Examples are easy to construct.  To be continued . . .

Comment: @ CnR: (continuation) I must leave for work RIGHT NOW, so I can't explain furhter at the moment.  So, please do me a favor, if you would:  dwell on these things a tad longer, and if you still have doubts, leave me a message *via* another comment and I'll try and get back to you when I get back, late tonight or tomorrow.  Meanwhile, Happy Holidays.